# how to set title to openlayers markers?

Tags: openlayers

I want to set title to OpenLayers Marker. But i doesn't find any thing.

in google maps i can easily do it like this

```
 var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            title: userType,
            clickable: true,
            map: map
        });
```

But in OpenLayers Marker

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(pos, new OpenLayers.Icon('images/'+color+'.png',size,offset), userType);
```

But when i acces `marker.markerText is giving undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this http://doesterr.github.com/OpenLayers-Examples/examples/marker-with-title.html

Comment: good one. personnaly prefer a standalone chartable popup, which appears on mouseover instead of title.